# using for loops and dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

So I have a dataframe called Swine_flu_cases that looks as follows (just an extract):

```
 Swine_flu_cases <- read.table(text = "Country    Date        Confirmed     
1   Egypt   2020-01-22         0                            
2   Egypt   2020-01-23         1                                
3   Algeria 2020-01-24         1                                
4   France  2020-01-25         1                                
5   Zambia  2020-01-26         1                            
6   Congo   2020-01-27         1", header =TRUE)
```

I am wanting to create a new variable called "days_since_first_case which should be a numeric vector which will subtract the the current date from the first time the country had their first confirmed swine flu case.

This is the code I used to create the new variable:

```
Swine_flu_cases %>% 
filter(Confirmed ==1) %>%
group_by(Country) %>% 
mutate(days_since_first_case = Date - min(Date))
```

The problem with this code is that it only gives me the rows where confirmed is equal to 1 and takes that minimum date and if i remove the filter it just takes the min date of the country and subtracts each date from it.

I don't know if I should possibly add a for loop to this, I am not familiar with for loops is why I opted to use this method.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this approach reusing some of your code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Format
Swine_flu_cases %>% mutate(Date=as.Date(Date)) -> Swine_flu_cases
#Code
Swine_flu_cases %>%
  left_join(Swine_flu_cases %>% 
              filter(Confirmed ==1) %>%
              group_by(Country) %>% 
              summarise(DateFirstCase = min(Date))) %>%
  mutate(DaysSinceFirstCase=DateFirstCase-Date)
```

Output:

```
  Country       Date Confirmed DateFirstCase DaysSinceFirstCase
1   Egypt 2020-01-22         0    2020-01-23             1 days
2   Egypt 2020-01-23         1    2020-01-23             0 days
3 Algeria 2020-01-24         1    2020-01-24             0 days
4  France 2020-01-25         1    2020-01-25             0 days
5  Zambia 2020-01-26         1    2020-01-26             0 days
6   Congo 2020-01-27         1    2020-01-27             0 days
```

Please let me know if that is what you want because I am also confused which output you want.

Comment: this is perfect thank you, the left_join function really helped thank you for the assistance

Comment: @DRC_mami Great! If you think this answer was useful you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer. It is up to you :) In this way you encourage other people to continue helping others !

Answer (score 0):

No need for a for loop. You can easily use the code you had, but with a date that only shows when having a case:

```
Swine_flu_cases %>%
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  mutate(
    case_date = ifelse(Confirmed == 1, Date, NA),
    days_since_first_case = Date - min(case_date)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the amount of days since the first the case got discovered in a certain country.
I thought Confirmed is the number of cases therefore I filtered for one and more cases. For testing I changed your example code and made up more cases and days for Egypt.

```
library(lubridate)

Swine_flu_cases <- read.table(text = "Country    Date        Confirmed     
1   Egypt   2020-01-22         0                            
2   Egypt   2020-01-23         1                                
3   Egypt   2020-01-24         5                                
4   Egypt   2020-01-25         7                                
5   Zambia  2020-01-26         1                            
6   Congo   2020-01-27         1", header =TRUE)  


Swine_flu_cases %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>% 
  filter(Confirmed >= 1) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  mutate(days_since_first_case = as.numeric(difftime(Date, min(Date), units = "days")))  %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Country Date       Confirmed days_since_first_case
  <chr>   <date>         <int>                 <dbl>
1 Egypt   2020-01-23         1                     0
2 Egypt   2020-01-24         5                     1
3 Egypt   2020-01-25         7                     2
4 Zambia  2020-01-26         1                     0
5 Congo   2020-01-27         1                     0
```